# Given a Pandas Concated Dataframe, delete both indexes from Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a large Python Pandas Dataframe that I concatenated together with. The Column names are all the same name.

```
combinedData = pd.concat([combinedData, data], ignore_index=True)
```

My output looks like this

```
              0         1                    2    3     4   ...                                                 7         8           9                    10     11
0           date      time                   id  lat  long  ...                                              tweet  retweets  favourites               source    geo     
1     2021-11-24  04:23:55  1463362723824107522             ...  RT @cloudpreacher: Infographic: Big Data Pipel...        41           0      Twitter Web App   True     
2     2021-11-24  04:23:33  1463362628483305478             ...  RT @eileeniorio: On Tucker tonight, #TheRealAn...        16           0  Twitter for Android   True     
3     2021-11-24  04:23:22  1463362581452582912             ...  RT @GlobalRepCentre: This is the last week to ...         3           0   Twitter for iPhone   True     
4     2021-11-24  04:22:42  1463362416662753282             ...  RT @eileeniorio: On Tucker tonight, #TheRealAn...        16           0      Twitter Web App  False     
...          ...       ...                  ...  ...   ...  ...                                                ...       ...         ...                  ...    ...     
5000  2021-11-24  04:37:17  1463366086708154368             ...  RT @KENS5: The actor says he was let go due to...         1           0      Twitter Web App   True     
5001  2021-11-24  04:37:17  1463366085495951364             ...  RT @CarolineLessar8: J’espère: « aucun enfant ...         2           0   Twitter for iPhone  False     
5002  2021-11-24  04:37:17  1463366085063884800             ...  RT @Leftylockdowns1: If the antiviral pill fro...         6           0  Twitter for Android   True     
5003  2021-11-24  04:37:16  1463366080529723398             ...  RT @Alfiedog9: @Ashmount @Eldever1 https://t.c...         6           0  Twitter for Android  False     
5004  2021-11-24  04:37:15  1463366078374068230             ...  RT @JilPrantner: @patriottakes If you do not b...        71           0  Twitter for Android   True
```

But I want my output to have no index (Remove the Column and Row Numbers that are Incrementing)

```
     date      time                   id  lat  long  ...                                              tweet  retweets  favourites               source    geo     
2021-11-24  04:23:55  1463362723824107522             ...  RT @cloudpreacher: Infographic: Big Data Pipel...        41           0      Twitter Web App   True     
2021-11-24  04:23:33  1463362628483305478             ...  RT @eileeniorio: On Tucker tonight, #TheRealAn...        16           0  Twitter for Android   True     
2021-11-24  04:23:22  1463362581452582912             ...  RT @GlobalRepCentre: This is the last week to ...         3           0   Twitter for iPhone   True     
2021-11-24  04:22:42  1463362416662753282             ...  RT @eileeniorio: On Tucker tonight, #TheRealAn...        16           0      Twitter Web App  False     
...          ...       ...                  ...  ...   ...  ...                                                ...       ...         ...                  ...    ...     
2021-11-24  04:37:17  1463366086708154368             ...  RT @KENS5: The actor says he was let go due to...         1           0      Twitter Web App   True     
2021-11-24  04:37:17  1463366085495951364             ...  RT @CarolineLessar8: J’espère: « aucun enfant ...         2           0   Twitter for iPhone  False     
2021-11-24  04:37:17  1463366085063884800             ...  RT @Leftylockdowns1: If the antiviral pill fro...         6           0  Twitter for Android   True     
2021-11-24  04:37:16  1463366080529723398             ...  RT @Alfiedog9: @Ashmount @Eldever1 https://t.c...         6           0  Twitter for Android  False     
2021-11-24  04:37:15  1463366078374068230             ...  RT @JilPrantner: @patriottakes If you do not b...        71           0  Twitter for Android   True
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can fix your column names by assigning your column names to the first row and then drop this first row. 
If you want to get rid of the automatically generated index, you'll have to define another column as index. In your case `id` seems to be the logical choice:

```
df = combinedData.rename(columns=combinedData.iloc[0]).drop(combinedData.index[0])
df = df.set_index(["id"])
print(df)
```

Output (slightly simplified from your example):

```
                           date      time                                              tweet retweets favourites               source    geo
id
1463362723824107522  2021-11-24  04:23:55  RT @cloudpreacher: Infographic: Big Data Pipel...       41          0      Twitter Web App   True
1463362628483305478  2021-11-24  04:23:33  RT @eileeniorio: On Tucker tonight, #TheRealAn...       16          0  Twitter for Android   True
1463362581452582912  2021-11-24  04:23:22  RT @GlobalRepCentre: This is the last week to ...        3          0   Twitter for iPhone   True
1463362416662753282  2021-11-24  04:22:42  RT @eileeniorio: On Tucker tonight, #TheRealAn...       16          0      Twitter Web App  False
1463366086708154368  2021-11-24  04:37:17  RT @KENS5: The actor says he was let go due to...        1          0      Twitter Web App   True
1463366085495951364  2021-11-24  04:37:17  RT @CarolineLessar8: J’espère: « aucun enfant ...        2          0   Twitter for iPhone  False
1463366085063884800  2021-11-24  04:37:17  RT @Leftylockdowns1: If the antiviral pill fro...        6          0  Twitter for Android   True
1463366080529723398  2021-11-24  04:37:16  RT @Alfiedog9: @Ashmount @Eldever1 https://t.c...        6          0  Twitter for Android  False
1463366078374068230  2021-11-24  04:37:15  RT @JilPrantner: @patriottakes If you do not b...       71          0  Twitter for Android   True
```